# Is the Feed's time relative to the newest post, or when I load the Feed?

Tags: support, android-app, android-app-feed

I would expect that the feed would show questions relative to when they were asked, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Here's a question which appears in the feed as of a few seconds ago:

[image]

But if I follow it, it was asked a half hour ago!

[image]

What behavior should I be expecting?

Comment: I've added a tag, plus changed from bug to support as you phrased it as such. If you want to change back to bug feel free. :)

Comment: Possibly this question doesn't apply anymore as the feed has been / is being redesigned.